# Save CV_16SC2 Mat to a file OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I want to save the CV_16SC2 matrix to a file. It is a result of initUndistortRectifyMap. I need it in a binary form, and later i want to read it from a file. What is the best method for that (YAML, XML is bad because of required space)?

Comment: You could write your own save method by iterating trough the matrix data.

Comment: @Adrian Its just hard to believe that it is not supported in openCV...

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cv-imwrite But you will have to convert your 2 channels to 3.

Comment: Tried that. Problem is that I have 2 channel 16 bit image, and according to that documentation it will not work. Mat::convertTo , and cvtColor does not seem to be the waz, because of the 2 channel nature of my mat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to use the provided ways [XML/YMAL Input and Output](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html). You have to write your own.

First make sure you have the correct type. Use  `cout << mat.type()` on your and check in the table below.

```
        C1  C2  C3  C4
CV_8U   0   8   16  24
CV_8S   1   9   17  25
CV_16U  2   10  18  26
CV_16S  3   11  19  27
CV_32S  4   12  20  28
CV_32F  5   13  21  29
CV_64F  6   14  22  30
```

Now you know the Number of channels and the correct type (bitcount) of your Matrixelements. 
For example Number `mat.type() == 11` would mean your type is: `CV_16SC2`, so 16 bit (signed short) and 2 channel.

If you don't now the relation between bitcount and variablename check the following:

```
Unsigned 8bits uchar 0~255
Mat: CV_8UC1, CV_8UC2, CV_8UC3, CV_8UC4

Signed 8bits char -128~127
Mat: CV_8SC1，CV_8SC2，CV_8SC3，CV_8SC4

Unsigned 16bits ushort 0~65535
Mat: CV_16UC1，CV_16UC2，CV_16UC3，CV_16UC4

Signed 16bits short -32768~32767
Mat: CV_16SC1，CV_16SC2，CV_16SC3，CV_16SC4

Signed 32bits int -2147483648~2147483647
Mat: CV_32SC1，CV_32SC2，CV_32SC3，CV_32SC4

Float 32bits float -1.18*10-38~3.40*10-38 
Mat: CV_32FC1，CV_32FC2，CV_32FC3，CV_32FC4

Double 64bits double 
Mat: CV_64FC1，CV_64FC2，CV_64FC3，CV_64FC4
```

To access them you need to use [at](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-at) with the correct [type](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#vec)!

In our CV_16SC2 (signed short and 2 channel) example that would mean: `Vec2s`.

`Vec` because we want a vector, `2` because there are 2 channel, `s`, because we want a signed short.

So to get the value of the second channel at position (5,7) into variable 's', you could write:

```
Vec2s v = mat.at<Vec2s>(5, 7);
short s = v[1];
```

Since you want to save your Matrix you probably want to do first write the size (rows, cols, channels) of your matrix and afterwards all the values.

Thanks to http://ninghang.blogspot.de/2012/11/list-of-mat-type-in-opencv.html for providing me the information to finally understand everything!