# Can I determine the number of channels in cv::Mat Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

This maybe rudimentary, but is it possible to know how many channels a `cv::Mat` has? For eg, we load an RGB image, I know there are 3 channels. I do the following operations, just to get the laplacian of the image, which is straight from the Opencv Documentation.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
     Mat src = imread(argv[1],1),src_gray,dst_gray,abs_dst_gray;

     cvtColor(src,src_gray,COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
     GaussianBlur( src, src, Size(3,3), 0, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT );
     Laplacian(src_gray,dst_gray,ddepth,kernel_size,scale,delta,BORDER_DEFAULT);
     convertScaleAbs(dst_gray,abs_dst_gray);
}
```

After converting to Grayscale, we should have only one channel. But how can I determine the number of channels of `abs_dst_gray` in program? Is there any function to do this? Or is it possible through any other method, which should be written by the programmer? Please help me here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at the anser i gave in another thread. I explained how to get the cannels and type of a matrix and how you can access single elements afterwards: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399344/save-cv-16sc2-mat-to-a-file-opencv/22102303#22102303

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Call `Mat.channels()` :

```
cv::Mat img(1,1,CV_8U,cvScalar(0));
std::cout<<img.channels();
```

Output:

```
1
```

which is the number of channels.

Also, try:

```
std::cout<<img.type();
```

Output:

```
0
```

which belongs to CV_8U (look [here](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h?rev=3837) at line 542). Study file `types_c.h` for each `define`.

Comment: This gives the data type @William. How do I get the no.of channels?

Comment: Of course. Everybody here are willing to help, @LakshmiNarayanan. Just post, and if I have some free time, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan Post the other doubt in a new question please.

Comment: @hetepeperfan I have asked it here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364987/knowing-the-value-of-an-mat-element-opencv
Please bare with me if its pretty rudimentary.

Comment: William's link seems dead. Here's a substitute: http://ninghang.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/list-of-mat-type-in-opencv.html

Answer (score 14):

you might use:

```
Mat::channels()
```

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-channels