# understanding a particular line in openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Can anybody tell me what does cvmSet actually doing in the following code. Especially `L0[y*5 + x]` this portion. Also, is the array declared a 1D array or 2D array? I guess it is 1D array. I just want to understand that particular line. Any help will be appreciated.

I mean if the value of array is calculated as L0[y*5 + x],so what is the role of the elements in L0,  then what is the point in initializing the array elements of 1D L0?

```
    float L0[]={
        -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        -1,-1,-1,-1,-1 };

    CvMat*  rgbMat = cvCreateMat(5, 5, CV_32FC1);

    for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
            cvmSet(rgbMat, y, x, L0[y*5 + x]);
    }
```

Comment: Why is your indentation all manky?

Comment: @user2481422 please change the title appropriate to the question asked,atleast mentioning about *cvmSet*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L0  is declared as 1D array of 25 elements, but it is interpreted as 2D 5x5, common thing actually. L0[y*5 + x] is used just for that, to get element of array that corresponds to [x,y] in 2D.

Comment: so this means that from float L0 to end of for first for loop means before IplImage* dst = cvCreateImage(cvSize(src->width,src->height),src->depth,3);  it is just creating a 2D matrix, right?

Comment: Yes, rgbMat is 5x5 2D matrix, created based on L0 (which seems to be some filter)

Comment: can I directly declare a 2D matrix instead of using mat?

Comment: so what is the role of the elements in L0, I mean if the value of array is calculated as L0[y*5 + x], then what is the point in initializing the array elements of 1D L0?

Comment: Please, vote up the answers you like and if any solves your question accept it. It's rude to ask so many questions and not give at least some credits. Thank you.

Comment: @William i tried it but it's requires 15 reputation for giving a vote and currently I have only 10 :( but once I have 15 I will surely vote for you

Comment: @William thanks :) I voted :) your answers are really helpful

Answer (score 1):

The line `cvmSet(image,x,y,value)` is explained:

set the pixel x,y in image with value.

The value is derived for the array L0. E.g. for pixel (x,y)=(1,2):

`value= L0[y*5 + x] = L0[2*5+1] = L0[11] = 2`.

Comment: so what is the role of the elements in L0, I mean if the value of array is calculated as L0[y*5 + x], then what is the point in initializing the array elements of 1D L0?

Comment: It's a mapping. X,Y coordinates are mapped into L0. It's a non-technical question and you'll find an answer in the theory.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364987/knowing-the-value-of-an-mat-element-opencv/17365489#17365489) thread.