# how to get the number of channels from an image, in OpenCV 2?

Tags: python, image, opencv, channel

The answers at [Can I determine the number of channels in cv::Mat Opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363886/can-i-determin-the-number-of-channels-in-cvmat-opencv) answer this question for OpenCV 1: you use the `Mat.channels()` method of the image.

But in cv2 (I'm using 2.4.6), the image data structure I have doesn't have a `channels()` method. I'm using Python 2.7.

Code snippet:

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(source)
ret, img = cam.read()
# Here's where I would like to find the number of channels in img.
```

Interactive attempt:

```
>>> img.channels()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'channels'
>>> type(img)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> img.dtype
dtype('uint8')
>>> dir(img)
['T',
 '__abs__',
 '__add__',
...
 'transpose',
 'var',
 'view']
# Nothing obvious that would expose the number of channels.
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use `img.shape`

It provides you the shape of img in all directions. ie number of rows, number of columns for a 2D array (grayscale image). For 3D array, it gives you number of channels also.

So if `len(img.shape)` gives you two, it has a single channel.

If `len(img.shape)` gives you three, third element gives you number of channels.

For more details, [visit here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html#accessing-image-properties)

Comment: This is outdated. Use @abhiTronix answer instead (or better yet my comment under his answer).

Answer (score 19):

I'm kind of late but there is another simple way out there:

Use `image.ndim` [Source](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ndim.html#numpy-ndarray-ndim), will give your right number of channels as below:

```py
if image.ndim == 2:

    channels = 1 #single (grayscale)

if image.ndim == 3:

    channels = image.shape[-1]
```

**Edit:** In one-liners:

```py
channels = image.shape[-1] if image.ndim == 3 else 1
```

Since a **image** is a nothing but a **numpy** array. Checkout OpenCV docs here: [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#af1d014cecd1510cdf580bf2ed7e5aafc)

Comment: Good technique, thank you. I implemented it as: `channels = 0 if img.ndim == 2 else img.shape[2]`. So if the image is grayscale then channels is 0, else channels is a number representing how many channels are in the 3rd array dimension (that's the correct place to read the data since dim 1 = height, dim 2 = width, dim 3 = color channels).

Comment: Should be `channels = image.shape[-1] if image.ndim > 1 else 1`, for RGBA images and others

Answer (score 1):

As i know, u should use image.shape[2] to determine number of channels, not len(img.shape), the latter gives the dimensions of the array.

Comment: Please read Abid's answer more closely ... he agrees that image.shape[2] gives the number of channels *when image.shape[2] exists*, which is when len(image.shape) == 3.

Comment: u  r right, LarsH. sorry for Abid, he's answer is more general.

Answer (score 1):

Not a fast but short alternative for determining the number of color channels

```py
len(cv2.split(img))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add here a self-contained script using the `PIL` library and another one using the `cv2` library

### CV2 Library script

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("full_path_to_image")

img_np = np.asarray(img)

print("img_np.shape: ", img_np.shape)
```

The last column of the last print will show the number of channels, for example

`img_np.shape:  (1200, 1920, 4)`

### PIL Library script

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.imread("full_path_to_image")

img_np = np.asarray(img)

print("img_np.shape: ", img_np.shape)
```

The last column of the last print will show the number of channels, for example

`img_np.shape:  (1200, 1920, 4)`

Note: from the scripts above you would be tempted (I was) to use `img_np.shape[2]` to retrieve the number of channels. However, if your image contains 1 channel (e.g., grayscale), that line would give you a problem (`IndexError: tuple index out of range`). Instead with just a simple print of shape (as I did in my script) you will get something like this

`img_np.shape:  (1200, 1920)`