# Print cvMat channels

Tags: c++, opencv

How can I print whether a `cvMat` is `RGB`, `BGR` or `GRAY`? The reason I need to do this is because I need to convert an image to `GRAY` and have been given errors such as this when trying `CV_RGB2GRAY`

`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor`

Comment: "whether a cv::Mat is RGB, BGR" - unfortunately, that information is nowhere saved. you can tell the number of channels and their type ( see answer below), but not the semantics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to know the number of channels input image has. cvtColor is expecting it to have 3 or 4 channels. Use channels() to determine what you have. The following information is taken directly from the answer in: [Can I determine the number of channels in cv::Mat Opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363886/can-i-determin-the-number-of-channels-in-cvmat-opencv)

```
cv::Mat img(1,1,CV_8U,cvScalar(0));
std::cout<<img.channels();
```

Output:

```
1
```

which is the number of channels.

This error also occurs when the image is empty. You can check for this using:

```
img.empty();
```

Source: [openCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871540/opencv-error-assertion-failed-scn-3-scn-4)