# Access a pixel of Mat in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, position, pixel, mat

I want to access to a pixel in OpenCV, in an image of type Mat.

Let's say I do:

```
Mat image;
```

I want to access to the pixel 30, 50 in the image.

I tried to do `image[30][50]`, but it did not work.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: More Information for pixel access: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#howtoscanimagesopencv
More Information for pixel access in Mat: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399344/save-cv-16sc2-mat-to-a-file-opencv/22102303#22102303

Answer (score 1):

- For grayscale:

  `uchar intensity = image.at<uchar>(y, x);`
- For color image:

  ```
  Vec3b intensity = image.at<Vec3b>(y, x);
  uchar blue = intensity.val[0];
  uchar green = intensity.val[1];
  uchar red = intensity.val[2];
  ```

Note: `x` is the horizontal axis and `y` is the vertical axis, i.e. `x=50, y=30`.