# Need help in finding out white color in an image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I'm am currently working on comparing two images to find out the difference in them. I now have two images in which I need to find the image who has white color inside them.

I want to implement this using OpenCv. I am new to OpenCv so it would helpful if someone could help me with this.

Comment: You may need to see http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html

Comment: I did look into it. I do not need to vary any threshold, I just want to findout whether the image contains any white pixel or not (I all ready have the image in gray scale).

Comment: In that example they may be used trackbar you can use fixed threshold instead.

Comment: I did that. I used the threshold "binary" and as a result the entire image is changed to black and white. Now I need to find which image has white pixel in them.

Comment: Can you show your image ?.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ZPIre3h.png . I actually have two sperate video clips, while playing them I need two find out which frame has white image (just for the image in the window which now has no white image).

Comment: [Threshold](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html) with higher value and [countNonZero](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#countnonzero), if it returns a value(you can set a threshold) then there is white pixel else no white pixel.

Comment: @Adi Did you solve your problem? You could accept the answer or tell us how you did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an image `Mat img`, then you can access pixel values with [img.at](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-at). You can check the type of your Mat with `img.type()`, so now you know which `type` you have to provide in `Mat.at<type>(x,y)`. ([More information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399344/save-cv-16sc2-mat-to-a-file-opencv/22102303#22102303))

Then just iterate over your image and stop if you found white pixels. Have a look into the [tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html) as well. This stuff is covered in there.

Comment: I have one question. After finding which type the image is what should I do?

Comment: you have to provide the type in the `.at()`. Please have a look at my other answer. In there is the accessing of Matrix elements explained in more depth and with an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399344/save-cv-16sc2-mat-to-a-file-opencv/22102303#22102303